# Amazon WS point to external VPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm a noob with amazon ws... I just wondering if it is possible, having a domain pointing to amazon EC2 IP, to tunneling, someway, to another IP/VPS...

I mean, going to that domain (amazon IP) It shows up content from my VPS (external IP different from amazon's).

Crazy?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

Modifying vhost with ProxyPass

```
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://xxx.xxx.xxx:80/
```

Ty for everything!

Answer (score 1):

In an *EC2 Instance* with the "amazon ip", you could forward the port `80` (for example) to an external ip (`<another-ip>`) using iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination <another-ip>:80
```

Also, you could use *Route 53* (or any other dns server) to manage your dns.

If you think about allocating a "elastic ip" to an external ip, it isnt possible.

Comment: Thank you for answering... I'm trying that command... but I think It didn't work... My point is having a domain pointing to amazon ec2 IP but serve an app deployed in an external VPS Is this possible?